# [].concat(["x","y"],"z") -> How to get [["x","y"],"z"] instead of ["x","y","z"]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

This is weird but I can't find any easy solution to this.

**Note**: I use immutability so I absolutly don't want to modify the original array (don't suggest using `push`)

`[].concat(["x","y"],"z")` -> How to get `[["x","y"],"z"]` instead of `["x","y","z"]` ?

Comment: You could always just use the constructor `Array(["x", "y"], "z")`. Only caveat is passing a single argument that's a number has a different behavior `Array(5); // new Array with .length == 5`

Comment: ...and ECMAScript 6 offers this: `Array.of(["x", "y"], "z");`, which can easily be polyfilled and doesn't suffer from the single numeric argument problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a nested array:

```
> [].concat([["x", "y"]], "z")

[["x", "y"], "z"]
```